# Isotope grid layout fails on window resize

Tags: responsive-design, jquery-isotope

I'm having problems with isotope in my site. I thought I tackled them all but now there is still a problem when resizing the window. On resize of the window the whole grid is moved way down on the page. This is not fixed by re-doing the layout when the window size changes. Triggering a .isotope('layout') always moves the whole grid to the bottom of the page. My code also implements infinite scroll, that is why I have the part on the hiddenelem's children. I'm also using bootstrap btw.

The (important) part of the code:

```
  if (typeof g_Isotopegrid === 'undefined') {
                    g_Isotopegrid = $('.grid').isotope({
                            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                            stamp: '.stamp',
                            masonry: {
                                columnWidth: 255,
                                gutter: 30
                            }
                        });                       
                }

              // Append all the hidden items to the visible items element
              hiddenElm.children().each(function () {
                var aItem = $(this);
                // Append the items to the visible div
                aItem.appendTo(visibleElm).imagesLoaded(function() {
                    g_Isotopegrid.isotope('appended', aItem);
                });

              });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that we were not using the direct container of the grid items as the element to apply isotope to.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap I never set static width:

```
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 255,
    gutter: 30
}
```

just item's class:

```
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-item',
    gutter: 30
}
```

When you are using Bootstrap is better for item width use bootstrap's classes.